# How to avoid duplicate data in my database in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have scrap a data from another website and saved it in my database which is working fine. However, anytime I refresh my application the scrapped data duplicate itself in my database.Any help would be highly appreciated. Below are my code

```
require 'open-uri'
require 'nokogiri'
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(open("www.example.com"))
entries = doc.css('.block')
@entriesArray = []
entries.each do |row|
    Scrap.create!(                  
    title: title = row.css('h2>a').text,
    link:  link = row.css('a')[0]['href'],
    day:   days =row.css('time').text)
    @entriesArray << Entry.new(title,link,days)
end
```

Comment: Did you consider a uniqueness validation and a unique index in the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `model` validation to raise error on `create!` if any validation fails.

```
class Scrap < ApplicationRecord
    validates_uniqueness_of :title
end
```

And, you can also use [**`first_or_create`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.8/active_record_querying.html#first_or_create) method to create a new record only if not exists in the database:

```
entries.each do |row|
    title = row.css('h2>a').text
    link = row.css('a')[0]['href']
    day = row.css('time').text

    Scrap.where(title: title).first_or_create(                  
      title: title,
      link: link,
      day: day
    )
    @entriesArray << Entry.new(title,link,days)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add an uniq index on, for instance, the `link` column on your database (this is to optimize the find_by and to enforce you'll not have duplicates with the same links, it's not needed, although it makes sense), since they'll be unique (you could go with title too, but they could repeat themselves? - not sure, it depends on what you're fetching)

And then check to see if you already have that `link` on the database, like so:

```
entries.each do |row|
        scrap = Scrap.create_with(title: row.css('h2>a').text, day: row.css('time').text).find_or_initialize_by(link: row.css('a')[0]['href'])
        @entriesArray << Entry.new(title,link,days) if scrap.new_record? && (scrap.save! if scrap.new_record?)
    end
```

(the last `if` is in case you just want to add the `Entry` if it's a new `Entry`, if you want to add it no matter what, just remove from `if scrap.new_record? ...` until `end`

Answer (score 0):

You want to add a uniqueness validator to your Scrap model like this:

```
validates :title, uniqueness: true 
validates :link, uniqueness: true
```

This will prevent the same record from being saved twice.